# What's the successor of `org.gradle.util.VersionNumber`

Tags: gradle, versioning

In gradle 7.3, I found the following source code:

```
package org.gradle.util;

import com.google.common.base.Objects;
import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

/**
 * This class is only here to maintain binary compatibility with existing plugins.
 *
 * @deprecated Will be removed in Gradle 8.0.
 */
@Deprecated
public class VersionNumber implements Comparable<VersionNumber> {
...
```

So is this feature dropped or moved? What's the new way of using VersionNumber related functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That class and many others in the `util` package were not intended to be used in plugins or anything outside of Gradle's codebase.

In [#16745](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/16745), the Gradle team formally deprecated many of the utility classes and moved/copied them into an internal utility package. Some utility classes have replacements as noted in their respective Javadoc, but some such as `VersionNumber` have no public replacement provided by Gradle. As such, this should be considered a private API and you should not use it anywhere in your project's build or plugins.

As an alternative, you can use a semver library of your choosing as a replacement.

Comment: thanks a lot! will migrate to it shortly